# Wordpress Dashboard Issue

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I'm new at Wordpress and I'm trying to update WP 4.6.6 to 4.8.1. The site is currently running the Eight Degree theme.

I performed a full backup of the home directory, updated the plugins and everything was working fine. When I tried to update WP to 4.8.1, the update did not take and PHP error notices began to appear at the top of the dashboard. I have to scroll way down the page past these notices in order to to see the dashboard tools in the sidebar.

This is what it looks like.

[WP dashboard with PHP notices appearing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ymbOw.png)

I logged out of WP and then tried to log back in but a plugin called "reCAPTCHA" was denying me access to the WP dashboard. After reading through some forums for a log in solution, I disabled the reCAPTCHA plugin (located in public-html/wp-content/plugins) by renaming the plugin folder "recaptcha" to "recaptcha1". I was then able to log into WP but the dashboard is now showing PHP error messages. I thought I could fix that issue by deleting the "reCAPTCHA" plugin but that did not work either.

The PHP notices appear as so:

Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in /home/rgolden82/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php on line 981

Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in /home/rgolden82/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php on line 999

I downloaded the plugin.php file and went to lines 981 and 999 and this is how they appear:

[plugin.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lf2Z4.png)

...and I still cannot upgrade my WP dashboard to 4.8.1.

I would greatly appreciate any assistance that can be offered in solving these issues.

Thanks,
Sam

Comment: What you should do is to disable all the plugins, upgrade your WP-site and then enable all plugins one by one to see if any of them isn't compatible.

Comment: Perfect, thank you so much!!!